# How to add dynamically resolve property type based on another property value in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have used Polymorphic relationships. So, right now I have the following TypeScript interface:

```
interface SubjectA {}
interface SubjectB {}
interface SubjectC {}

enum SubjectType {
  SubjectA = 'Subject A',
  SubjectB = 'Subject B',
  SubjectC = 'Subject C',
}

interface ExampleSubject {
  type: SubjectType;
  subject: SubjectA | SubjectB | SubjectC
}
```

In this example, you can see, `ExampleSubject.subject` has three possible subject types (`SubjectA`, `SubjectB` `SubjectC`).
Now here I want it should resolve its type dynamically. For example, if `ExampleSubject.type` is `SubjectType.SubjectA` in that case `ExampleSubject.subject` should be `SubjectA`.

Please guide me, How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a discriminated union type ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html))

```
interface SubjectA { someVar: 'a' }
interface SubjectB { someVar: 'b' }
interface SubjectC { someVar: 'c' }

enum SubjectType {
  SubjectA = 'Subject A',
  SubjectB = 'Subject B',
  SubjectC = 'Subject C',
}

interface ExampleSubjectA {
  type: SubjectType.SubjectA;
  subject: SubjectA
}
interface ExampleSubjectB {
  type: SubjectType.SubjectB;
  subject: SubjectB
}
interface ExampleSubjectC {
  type: SubjectType.SubjectC;
  subject: SubjectC
}

type ExampleSubject = ExampleSubjectA | ExampleSubjectB | ExampleSubjectC
```

```
const subjectA: SubjectA = {
  someVar: 'a'
}
const subjectB: SubjectB = {
  someVar: 'b'
}

const exampleSubjectValid: ExampleSubject = {
  type: SubjectType.SubjectA,
  subject: subjectA
}
const exampleSubjectInvalid: ExampleSubject = {
  type: SubjectType.SubjectA,
  subject: subjectB
}
/* Type '{ type: SubjectType.SubjectA; subject: SubjectB; }' is not assignable to type 'ExampleSubject'.
  The types of 'subject.someVar' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.(2322) */
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=2&pln=32&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGArCCwCCyA3gFDLIDOA9gLYQBqcUAXMgORzukC%20pokWIhQYceMACES5KnUbM27TNz4Do8JGiy58AYWkUa9Jqw4IVpUhBDpaWsfgAqATwAOKMhVE7CyALwc3uLIBOwANDJB%20FIB7FFgyBLhkdri%20rHxyLrJfPzg6sLIAKIAHnC0rgA2EPFEnshgbhBs8S7uAHS1ANwylKn4Lf2EvHmCGiil5VU1Q1L1je6DDmBtEJ2zPYZDSz4SI2pCmpMV1fH680074qvry7qbVNv2ProjpAsTZSczy-7FX9NasgAD7-KanWYgsHfM6WBDUECUBJ9ZYEK74IgBepGeSmTgWeGI5GzdGSP7YuQmRTKN6EpHICAAiHLJiVYAAEzYx0BQ3JMg%20pJutQiW2WbBRPgIIzpCUZ4J%20PgAkiAAG5wNmc6E835Y-mXZ7XJq3SUix5is27EZAA)

Note: The `SubjectX` interface definitions need to differ in some way otherwise TypeScript will collapse them into the same concept and they will effectively be three aliases for the same interface (and therefore can not be discriminated). This is why `someVar` was included in the example / TS playground link

Answer (score 1):

For that, you'd use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) rather than an interface. You already have the discriminant (`SubjectType`). Here's how you'd write the union:

```
type ExampleSubject =
    | { type: SubjectType.SubjectA; subject: SubjectA }
    | { type: SubjectType.SubjectB; subject: SubjectB }
    | { type: SubjectType.SubjectC; subject: SubjectC };
```

Then if you had `x` which was of type `ExampleSubject`, you could narrow the type of `x.subject` by checking `x.type`:

```
if (x.type === SubjectType.SubjectA) {
    console.log(x.subject);
    //             ^? (property) subject: SubjectA
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGArCCwCCyA3gFDIXJwBcyAzmFKAOYDcpAvqaJLIihhx4wAIRLlKmWgyYg2nbuGjwkaLLnwBhcZWQJpjFuy6kIIdAFs1Q-ABUAngAcUZXYI2FkAXmQAid8LIBL4ANBIUAfhiPv7qgSKh4dYe2jGRYMiaiSZgTigAogAecBaOADYQ6d5JAD4kyLnOtOkOzgB06QSs9HH4zb2eXLp1xA15-TZgrRAdAyLddAMTHmJDlCNjTcnC07OTmgtL21rIHOykACZ4ZXBQKBUZhbRFJeWVA+fAMMgAFIVtjRQXmBxymeT2HgIAEodJQEAB7EB0eEVNpleHMP5tRaTKHsXQAegJuhJugAegB+X6OKDw5xQXIwnEeZbCAicIA)

Note that I've put something inside `SubjectA`, `SubjectB`, and `SubjectC` so TypeScript can tell them apart. Since TypeScript's type system is *structural*, not *nominal*, when doing sample types like the above it's important to put something in the types to differentiate them from each other. Otherwise, they're compatible with each other, which can take you down the wrong path...

Comment: Thanks @Tobias! How did I miss that typo?!